# Converting a sequence of Json Object to An Rdd

Tags: scala, playframework, apache-spark

Iam currently having a json object say student.json. The Structure looks something like this

```
{"serialNo":"1","name":"Rahul"}
{"serialNo":"2","name":"Rakshith"}

case class Student(serialNo:Int,name:String)
```

student.json is a huge file which Iam planning to parse through a spark job. And the snippet :

```
    import play.api.libs.json.{ Json, JsObject, JsString }
.....
.....
    for(jsonLine <-sc.textFile("student.json")
    student<- Json.parse(jsonLine).asOpt[Student])
yield(student.serialNumber -> student.name)
```

Is there a better way to do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `student.json` is a huge file, and each line is just a **valid** json object, you should do:

```
val myRdd = sc.textFile("student.json").map(l=> Json.parse(l).asOpt[Student])
```

If you want to get the RDD to your local master, you can:

```
val students = myRdd.collect()..// then you can do operate it in the old fashion way.
```

I saw you are importing `play.api.libs.json` which is from the **Play Framework**. I don't think running a Spark program in a web application is a good idea...

Comment: dont you think the statement needs to be sc.textFile("student.json").map(l=> Json.parse(l).asOpt[Student]) rather than filter. Btw iam using spark jobs for parsing the file and iam saving the data in elasticsearch .